# Ошибка "[errno 5] input/output error" при установке ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, установка

При установке ubuntu 20.04 на ноутбук **acer nitro 5 an515-52-785s** вылазит ошибка `[errno 5] input/output error`.

Образ собирал через unetbootin, предварительно скачав его с официального сайта.

Какие советы можете дать?

Comment: Попробуйте установить на виртуальной машине сначала

Comment: попробуйте не «собирать образ» («через» что-то там), а просто **записать** этот файл на блочное устройство. если используемая вами операционная система на это неспособна (ms/windows традиционно этого не умеет), можно воспользоваться альтернативными способами: записать этот файл на dvd, воспользоваться для записи другим компьютером, где установлена полноценная операционная система (gnu/linux, например) и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: Такой вопрос, а убунту можно установить через микро сд?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

проблема была решена, заключалась она в том, что я производил установку с микро сд карты. Попробовав установить через флешку, всё заработало